# Steam retail Serial Number "Not available for purchase in your country"

Tags: steam, crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy

I have a retail copy of the Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy for PC.

When I try and redeem my code, Steam issues the error message:

> The product is not available for purchase in your country. The
>   purchase is cancelled.

I have checked the product at the Steam store and the product does seem to be available in my country as I am able to purchase it through the Steam store.

Is it a problem with my serial code? Do I need to contact steam regarding this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely bought a game key for another region and the region lock prevents you from activating it. Make sure to check if the website you bought it from indicates any sort of region lock for this key.

More info on the different region definitions can be found [here](https://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Crash-Bandicoot-N-Sane-Trilogy-for-PC/).

Comment: I bought it straight from the store in my region to be honest

Comment: @BarrJ You mean at a brick & mortar store like Gamestop or whatever your local equivalent is? Weird. I'd go back to the store and complain that they sold you a faulty copy. Depending on where you live, you have been sold a defective product and are entitled to a refund. If possible, get the Steam app on your phone and try to redeem the code while in their presence to show that it's indeed a problem. Or you can even do it straight from the website, no mobile app needed.

Comment: Yea, I think I will do it, tried to contact customer support to no avail, I'll see if I can go and get a new copy or refund at the least.

Comment: Also possible to see package-based region restrictions on [SteamDB](https://steamdb.info), where a package can contain licenses to one or more apps and it's the packages themselves which are region restricted.